# Erro em tipo de variável

Tags: c++, string

Qual correção tenho que fazer para este código executar sem erro?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int anoNasc, idade, anoAtual = 2020;
    char categoria;

    cout <<"Digite o ano de nascimento: ";
    cin >> anoNasc;
    idade = anoAtual - anoNasc;

    if (idade >= 7 && idade <= 12){

        categoria = "Infantil";
    }
    cout <<"Sua "<<idade<<" anos sua categoria é"<<categoria;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estude os tipos de dados em C/C++. Ao declarar `char categoria;` você está dizendo que a variável categoria comprta um único caractere e não uma string.

Comment: Sim, e sempre leia com atenção o erro que o compilador mostra. Ali vai ter informações pra te ajudar a identificar o que está de errado com o código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para resolver o problema descrito você deve mudar o tipo da variável `categoria` para `string`, o tipo que você usou só permite um caractere e não um texto todo.

Não esqueça de fazer o `include <string>`.

Comment: Obrigado, aqui deu certo. vlw.